# Building your own google wave federation

Tags: google-wave, federation

I'm looking to learn about running my own google wave server. There are videos on how to set it up and get it in the command line, but my question is.. okay - where do you go from there? How do you take this service that is running in the command line and apply it to the web? Is there documentation on doing just that?

I have looked at the embedded API, but I do not think that's what I want. I'd also love for the frontend to be built in PHP - would anyone have any idea how to communicate PHP to Wave?

Thanks,
Matt Mueller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay ya'll. I emailed a few of the key Google Wave developers and surprisingly one of them responded! Here's what he said:

> "Thanks for contacting me.
>   Unfortunately there's still a big gap
>   between the code we have opened so far
>   and building a UI. The conversation
>   model describes how to interpret a
>   wave as a conversation but we have yet
>   to open up the code that does that (we
>   will though!). So it would be a big
>   challenge at the moment."

So we can only wait I suppose!